# how to create a javascript rusable class to pass parameters to ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery

im new in JS,im looking for a way to create a class or function,reusable everywhere in my code,just pass it parameters and get the result,because currently I am doing like this:

```
$.ajax({

          dataType: "json",
          type: "POST",
          url: "@Url.Action("power","Ranking")",
          contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
          data: JSON.stringify({ "regionalManager": tmpString }),
          success: function (result) {
       })}
```

I write this every time I need, and im sick of it,

Comment: Just write a simple function that takes a minimal amount of parameters and returns the ajax object.

Comment: Reusability code completely depends of nature of programming and requirement. You should specify your requirement so we can help you that how could you reuse the ajax function.

Comment: Sorry, but just ignore that ^^.  In this instance it's quite obvious what you're trying to do and it has nothing to do with the *"nature of programming"* and definitely nothing to do with *"requirement"*.  Just put it in a function and return the ajax object - job done.

Comment: @Dipakchavda I need to pass parameters to my controller but most of the times I am passing a single parameter,any way I have to write this ajax everytime

Comment: what is the language @Url.Action("power","Ranking") you used apart from javascript ?

Comment: does @Url.Action("power","Ranking")" is dynamic?

Comment: @Archer write a sample please

Comment: @Dipakchavda mvc-c#

Comment: jQuery has `$.get` and `$.post`, maybe you could use that.

Comment: @papagallo See nearly every answer below for a sample.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
function sendAjaxCustom(DataType,Type,Url,Ctype,Data){
      $.ajax({
          dataType: DataType,
          type: Type,
          url: Url,
          contentType: Ctype,
          data: Data,
          success: function (result) {
          return result;
       })}
}
```

You can call this function in JS like

```
var result = sendAjaxCustom("json","POST",'@Url.Action("power","Ranking")',"application/json; charset=utf-8",JSON.stringify({ "regionalManager": tmpString }));
```

you will have the result in result variable.

Answer (score 3):

Just create a simple function with your variables that need to change between calls and return the $.ajax result from there.

```
function ajaxWrapper(url, data, callback) {
  return $.ajax({
    dataType: 'json',
    type: 'POST',
    url: url,
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    data: JSON.stringify(data),
    success: callback
  });
}
```

When you want to call it:

```
ajaxWrapper('http://www.google.com/', { hello: 'world' }, function(result) {
    console.log(result);
});
```

With the callback it's much more reusable, since you can use this anywhere and change what you do on completion of the function wherever you use it.

Answer (score 3):

You can create a function like this

```
function ajax(url, data) {
  $.ajax({
      dataType: "json",
      type: "POST",
      url: url,
      contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
      data: data,
      success: function (result) {
   })}
}
```

Pass the url if it's dynamic and the object data on the second parameter.

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution is to return an object and pass it to the ajax and if some change is required then you can update the properties of the object before calling the ajax service

```
function commonAjaxParams() {
    return {
      dataType: "json",
      type: "POST",
      url: "@Url.Action("power","Ranking")",
      contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
      //and so on that are common properties
    }
}

//now in your application first call the function to get the common props
var commonParams = commonAjaxParams();
//change or add an parameter to your liking
commonParams.type = 'GET';
commonParams.success = function(){...} //if this action is need
commonPramss.error = function(){...}

//now call you ajax action
$.ajax(commonParams)
```

Answer (score 1):

There is another way in which you may call the ajax function and you may get success, fail response return.

The benefit is you manage success or fail response independently for each ajax request.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  function ajaxRequest(dataType, requestMethod, dataURL, jsonData) {
    return $.ajax({
      dataType: dataType,
      type: requestMethod,
      url: dataURL,
      contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
      data: JSON.stringify(jsonData)
    });
  }

  var jsonData = {
    "regionalManager": "jason bourne"
  };
  ajaxRequest(
      "json",
      "POST"
      "@Url.Action('power','Ranking')",
      jsonData)
    .success((data) {
      console.log("success");
    }).error((err) {
      console.log("error");
    }).done(() {
      console.log("done");
    });
});
```